# How to finish build the whole pipeline before running a new job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

This is a Jenkins relevant problem.

I have a Jenkins cluster which contains 10 windows slave nodes that are supposed to run the same pipeline(suppose it's job A->B->C)

Suppose I have new job A waiting in the queue, and a slave node just finished a job A and will trigger a job B, how can I make sure that this slave node will run job B first instead of running this long-time-waiting job A.

Thank a lot for your help.

---

A solution I have tried by using Priority Sorter Plugin, I've set job C with the highest priority, B second, and A with the lowest priority.

I was hoping while choosing a new job to run, the scheduler will schedule the job with higher priority(which in the case above, should be B instead of A)

Yet this solution fails, because scheduler will schedule job(A) to slave node before the newly triggered job(B) is added into Queue and re-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Even without [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/PrioritySorter/) you should be able to block starting job `A` by:

- set *Execute concurrent builds if necessary* in job `A` configuration.
- add additional *Build* step *Trigger/call builds on other projects* and set *Block until the triggered projects finish their builds*.

You can in the same manner configure jobs `B` and `C`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't find Block until the triggered projects finish their builds, does it include by any plugin?

Comment: Actually I was using  Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin but I can't find Block until the triggered projects finish their builds.

Comment: Double check that you are triggering from **Build Step**, not *Post-Build*.